# Java regex challenge - adding a prefix only when needed

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a a regex which will add a prefix (foo) to a word (bar)
only when it's not there already and when there are multiple appearances of the word bar.
Also ignore capitalize letters

String s = " uncle bar, is a foo bar kind of guy when he is at the bar "

so trying the following:

```
String s = " uncle bar, is a foo bar kind of guy when he is at the bar ";    
Pattern p;
Matcher m; 
p = Pattern.compile("(?i) bar ");
m = p.matcher(s);
if(m.find()){
       s =  s.replaceAll("(?i) bar ", " foo bar ");
}
```

This will result in adding foo, even when it already there.
i.e.  "foo foo bar kind of guy"
I need a regex to take into consideration the prefix of my pattern when trying to match it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative lookbehind to do this

```
s.replaceAll("(?i)(?<!foo )bar", "foo bar")
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj I am really sorry Avinash, but I usually try to solve the problem on IDE than copy it here after checking. Which made it 4 min.

Answer (score 1):

Use a negative lookbehind assertion.

```
s.replaceAll("(?i)(?<!\\bfoo )bar\\b", "foo bar");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lU4wM0/6)